# In XMod Pro, do I need a separate module for displaying a dynamic grid?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm new to XMod Pro and I have only been able to create simple tables. There are two links provided on the website (maybe, there are more) and they contain examples of grids/tables that display data from an external data source - which is precisely what I want to do.

http://dnndev.com/Products/XModPro/Demo/TableView.aspx - I want a grid like this and,

http://www.dnndev.com/Products/XMod/XModDemos/GridLayoutSample.aspx - I don't even have a grid like this.

What I presently have as a grid is very simple and unformatted table representation of my data. Do help.

Answer (score 0):

You should download their table sorter module kit, which can be installed like a typical module on Dotnetnuke. From there you can open it up and see exactly how it was built.

http://dnndev.com/Products/Free-XMod-Pro-Kits/Tablesorter.aspx